# How to set minify html in Production Mode

Tags: magento2.2.7

I'm very much aware of the following commands that can change JS/CSS settings whilst in Production Mode:

```
bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0
bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0
bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0
bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0
```

`1 = On, 2 = Off`

But how do I set **Minify HTML**?

Comment: You can use this extension
https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-minify.html

Comment: If you want to use default magento feature then check screenshot https://potatocommerce.com/media/blogposts/minify-magento-2/minify-html-magento-2.png

Answer (score 1):

Minify Html:

```
dev/template/minify_html
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Command for - Disable(0) / Enable(1) from SSH/Putty/CMD.**

Merge Minify JS

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0`

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0`

---

JS Bundling

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0`

---

Merge Minify CSS

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0`

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0`

---

CSS Critical Path

`php bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 0`

---

Minify HTML

`php bin/magento config:set dev/template/minify_html 0`

---

**Note: In last don't forget to run below command**

`php bin/magento cache:clean`